# Disable all WooCommerce shipping methods, except Local Pickup, when custom checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I am running into an issue with hiding shipping methods when a custom local pickup checkbox is selected during the shipping step in checkout.

Ideally, checking this custom checkbox would set the chosen shipping method to local pickup and disable/hide all other available methods. All available methods should consequently be available when unchecked.

Below is the code I currently have in place, and is somewhat functional in that it does hide and uncheck all other available methods except local pickup. However, the total at checkout still includes the shipping cost as if the other shipping method is still selected.

After reading up on this, it seems I need to incorporate ajax/php to accomplish this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//the following code is responsible for custom checkout functions
window.onload = function(){
//Define Shipping Variables
const shipFirstName = document.querySelector('#shipping_first_name');
const shipLastName = document.querySelector('#shipping_last_name');
const shipPhone = document.querySelector('#shipping_phone');
const shipCompany = document.querySelector('#shipping_company');
const shipAddress = document.querySelector('#shipping_address_1');
const shipAddress2 = document.querySelector('#shipping_address_2');
const shipCity = document.querySelector('#shipping_city');
const shipState = document.querySelector('#shipping_state');
const shipStateOption = shipState.options[shipState.selectedIndex];
const shipZip = document.querySelector('#shipping_postcode');
const shipCountry = document.querySelector('#shipping_country');

//Define Shipping Field Input Container Variables
const shipFirstNameField = document.querySelector('#shipping_first_name_field');
const shipLastNameField = document.querySelector('#shipping_last_name_field');
const shipPhoneField = document.querySelector('#shipping_phone_field');
const shipCompanyField = document.querySelector('#shipping_company_field');
const shipAddressField = document.querySelector('#shipping_address_1_field');
const shipAddress2Field = document.querySelector('#shipping_address_2_field');
const shipCityField = document.querySelector('#shipping_city_field');
const shipStateField = document.querySelector('#shipping_state_field');
const shipStateContainer = document.querySelector('select2-shipping_state-container');
const shipZipField = document.querySelector('#shipping_postcode_field');
const shipCountryField = document.querySelector('#shipping_country_field');
const shipDeliveryField = document.querySelector('#e_deliverydate_0_field');

//Define Billing Variables
const billFirstName = document.querySelector('#billing_first_name');
const billLastName = document.querySelector('#billing_last_name');
const billPhone = document.querySelector('#billing_phone');
const billCompany = document.querySelector('#billing_company');
const billAddress = document.querySelector('#billing_address_1');
const billAddress2 = document.querySelector('#billing_address_2');
const billCity = document.querySelector('#billing_city');
const billState = document.querySelector('#billing_state');
const billStateOption = billState.options[billState.selectedIndex];
const billStateContainer = document.querySelector('#select2-billing_state-container');
const billZip = document.querySelector('#billing_postcode');

//Define Qualifying Field Inputs & Values
const pickUpBtn = document.querySelector('#pick-up-qualifier');
const copyBtn = document.querySelector('#copy_shipping_to_billing');

//Define Default Value of Local Pick Up as False
var localPickUp = false;
    
//Set Conditions Based on Selection of In-Store PickUp
function localPickUpSelection(){
    if (pickUpBtn.checked) {
        localPickUp = true;
        shipFirstNameField.style.display = "none";
        shipFirstNameField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipLastNameField.style.display = "none";
        shipLastNameField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipPhoneField.style.display = "none";
        shipPhoneField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCompanyField.style.display = "none";
        shipCompanyField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipAddressField.style.display = "none";
        shipAddressField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipAddress2Field.style.display = "none";
        shipAddress2Field.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCityField.style.display = "none";
        shipCityField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipStateField.style.display = "none";
        shipStateField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipZipField.style.display = "none";
        shipZipField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCountryField.style.display = "none";
        shipCountryField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        //shipDeliveryField.classList.add("rcb-custom-hide");

    } else{
        localPickUp = false;
        //shipDeliveryField.style.display = "block";
        shipFirstNameField.style.display = "block";
        shipFirstNameField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipLastNameField.style.display = "block";
        shipLastNameField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipPhoneField.style.display = "block";
        shipPhoneField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCompanyField.style.display = "block";
        shipCompanyField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipAddressField.style.display = "block";
        shipAddressField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipAddress2Field.style.display = "block";
        shipAddress2Field.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCityField.style.display = "block";
        shipCityField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipStateField.style.display = "block";
        shipStateField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipZipField.style.display = "block";
        shipZipField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCountryField.style.display = "block";
        shipCountryField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        //shipDeliveryField.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
    }
};

//Filter Available Shipping Methods Based on In-Store Pick Up Selection
function deliveryFilter(){
    
    const shippingMethods = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='shipping_method[0]']");
    const alwaysVisibleInput = document.querySelector("input[id^='shipping_method_0_local_pickup']");
    const alwaysVisibleLabel = document.querySelector("label[for^='shipping_method_0_local_pickup']");
    var shippingMethodLabels = document.querySelectorAll("label[for^='shipping_method_0']");
    
    if (localPickUp === true){
        shippingMethods.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.add("rcb-custom-hide");
            alwaysVisibleInput.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
        });
        shippingMethodLabels.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.add("rcb-custom-hide");
            alwaysVisibleLabel.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
        });
        
        shippingMethods.checked = false;
        alwaysVisibleInput.checked = true;
        
        shipFirstName.value = billFirstName.value;
        shipLastName.value = billLastName.value;
        shipPhone.value = billPhone.value;
        shipCompany.value = billCompany.value;
        shipAddress.value = billAddress.value;
        shipAddress2.value = billAddress2.value;
        shipCity.value = billCity.value;
        shipState.value = billState.value;
        shipZip.value = billZip.value;
        
        console.log("Billing information has been copied to shipping inputs successfully.");
        
    }else {
        shippingMethods.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
        });
        shippingMethodLabels.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
        });
    };
};

//Copy Shipping Field Information to Billing Fields
copyBtn.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        var shipState = document.querySelector('#shipping_state');
        var shipStateOption = shipState.options[shipState.selectedIndex];
        billStateContainer.textContent = shipStateOption.text;
        console.log(shipStateOption.text);
        billFirstName.value = shipFirstName.value;
        billLastName.value = shipLastName.value;
        billPhone.value = shipPhone.value;
        billCompany.value = shipCompany.value;
        billAddress.value = shipAddress.value;
        billAddress2.value = shipAddress2.value;
        billCity.value = shipCity.value;
        billState.value = shipState.value;
        billZip.value = shipZip.value;
    } 
});
    
//Define Checkout Form Variables
const finalCheckoutStep = document.querySelector('.wpmc-step-payment');
    
//Observe Class Change in Final Checkout Step & Filter Delivery Options
var ob = new MutationObserver(function() {
    deliveryFilter();
});
ob.observe(finalCheckoutStep, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ["class"]
});
    
//Run localPickUpSelection Function on Page Load
window.onload = localPickUpSelection();
    
//Run localPickUpSelection Function When Checkbox Value Changes
pickUpBtn.addEventListener('change', localPickUpSelection);
    
};
</script>
```

I tried hiding/disabling shipping methods via javascript, which worked, however the cart total is still reflecting a shipping cost when Local Pickup is selected.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is running into this issue, I did end up finding the solution.

New code, tested and works, below. The key being the segmentation of functions and the addition of jQuery(document.body).trigger("update_checkout");

```js
//the following code is responsible for custom checkout functions
window.onload = function(){

//Define Shipping Variables
const shipFirstName = document.querySelector('#shipping_first_name');
const shipLastName = document.querySelector('#shipping_last_name');
const shipPhone = document.querySelector('#shipping_phone');
const shipCompany = document.querySelector('#shipping_company');
const shipAddress = document.querySelector('#shipping_address_1');
const shipAddress2 = document.querySelector('#shipping_address_2');
const shipCity = document.querySelector('#shipping_city');
const shipState = document.querySelector('#shipping_state');
const shipStateOption = shipState.options[shipState.selectedIndex];
const shipZip = document.querySelector('#shipping_postcode');
const shipCountry = document.querySelector('#shipping_country');

//Define Shipping Field Input Container Variables
const shipFirstNameField = document.querySelector('#shipping_first_name_field');
const shipLastNameField = document.querySelector('#shipping_last_name_field');
const shipPhoneField = document.querySelector('#shipping_phone_field');
const shipCompanyField = document.querySelector('#shipping_company_field');
const shipAddressField = document.querySelector('#shipping_address_1_field');
const shipAddress2Field = document.querySelector('#shipping_address_2_field');
const shipCityField = document.querySelector('#shipping_city_field');
const shipStateField = document.querySelector('#shipping_state_field');
const shipStateContainer = document.querySelector('select2-shipping_state-container');
const shipZipField = document.querySelector('#shipping_postcode_field');
const shipCountryField = document.querySelector('#shipping_country_field');
const shipDeliveryField = document.querySelector('#e_deliverydate_0_field');

//Define Billing Variables
const billFirstName = document.querySelector('#billing_first_name');
const billLastName = document.querySelector('#billing_last_name');
const billPhone = document.querySelector('#billing_phone');
const billCompany = document.querySelector('#billing_company');
const billAddress = document.querySelector('#billing_address_1');
const billAddress2 = document.querySelector('#billing_address_2');
const billCity = document.querySelector('#billing_city');
const billState = document.querySelector('#billing_state');
const billStateOption = billState.options[billState.selectedIndex];
const billStateContainer = document.querySelector('#select2-billing_state-container');
const billZip = document.querySelector('#billing_postcode');

//Define Qualifying Field Inputs & Values
const pickUpBtn = document.querySelector('#pick-up-qualifier');
const copyBtn = document.querySelector('#copy_shipping_to_billing');

//Define Default Value of Local Pick Up
var localPickUp = this;
    
//Set Conditions Based on Selection of In-Store PickUp
function localPickUpSelection(){
    if (pickUpBtn.checked) {
        window.localPickUp = true;
        console.log("localPickUp set to True");
        shipFirstNameField.style.display = "none";
        shipFirstNameField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipLastNameField.style.display = "none";
        shipLastNameField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipPhoneField.style.display = "none";
        shipPhoneField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCompanyField.style.display = "none";
        shipCompanyField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipAddressField.style.display = "none";
        shipAddressField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipAddress2Field.style.display = "none";
        shipAddress2Field.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCityField.style.display = "none";
        shipCityField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipStateField.style.display = "none";
        shipStateField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipZipField.style.display = "none";
        shipZipField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCountryField.style.display = "none";
        shipCountryField.classList.add("woocommerce-validated");
        //shipDeliveryField.classList.add("rcb-custom-hide");

    } else{
        window.localPickUp = false;
        console.log("localPickUp set to False");
        //shipDeliveryField.style.display = "block";
        shipFirstNameField.style.display = "block";
        shipFirstNameField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipLastNameField.style.display = "block";
        shipLastNameField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipPhoneField.style.display = "block";
        shipPhoneField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCompanyField.style.display = "block";
        shipCompanyField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipAddressField.style.display = "block";
        shipAddressField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipAddress2Field.style.display = "block";
        shipAddress2Field.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCityField.style.display = "block";
        shipCityField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipStateField.style.display = "block";
        shipStateField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipZipField.style.display = "block";
        shipZipField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        shipCountryField.style.display = "block";
        shipCountryField.classList.remove("woocommerce-validated");
        //shipDeliveryField.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
    }
};

//Function that deselects all available shipping methods and selects Local Pickup, if Local Pickup is True
function updateShippingMethods(){
    const shippingMethods = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='shipping_method[0]']");
    const alwaysVisibleInput = document.querySelector("input[id^='shipping_method_0_local_pickup']");
    if (window.localPickUp === true){
        shippingMethods.forEach((item) => {
            item.checked = false;
            alwaysVisibleInput.checked = true;
        });
    };
};

//Function that refreshes checkout page to reflect changes to shipping methods
function updateCheckout(){
    jQuery(document.body).trigger("update_checkout");
};
    
//Filter to hide all available shipping methods based on local pick up selection
function deliveryFilter(){
    
    const shippingMethods = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='shipping_method[0]']");
    const alwaysVisibleInput = document.querySelector("input[id^='shipping_method_0_local_pickup']");
    const alwaysVisibleLabel = document.querySelector("label[for^='shipping_method_0_local_pickup']");
    var shippingMethodLabels = document.querySelectorAll("label[for^='shipping_method_0']");
    
    if (window.localPickUp === true){
        shippingMethods.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.add("rcb-custom-hide");
            alwaysVisibleInput.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
        });
        shippingMethodLabels.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.add("rcb-custom-hide");
            alwaysVisibleLabel.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
        });
        
        shipFirstName.value = billFirstName.value;
        shipLastName.value = billLastName.value;
        shipPhone.value = billPhone.value;
        shipCompany.value = billCompany.value;
        shipAddress.value = billAddress.value;
        shipAddress2.value = billAddress2.value;
        shipCity.value = billCity.value;
        shipState.value = billState.value;
        shipZip.value = billZip.value;
        
        console.log("Billing information has been copied to shipping inputs successfully.");
        
    } else {
        shippingMethods.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
        });
        shippingMethodLabels.forEach((item) => {
            item.classList.remove("rcb-custom-hide");
        });
    };
};

//Copy Shipping Field Information to Billing Fields
copyBtn.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        var shipState = document.querySelector('#shipping_state');
        var shipStateOption = shipState.options[shipState.selectedIndex];
        billStateContainer.textContent = shipStateOption.text;
        console.log(shipStateOption.text);
        billFirstName.value = shipFirstName.value;
        billLastName.value = shipLastName.value;
        billPhone.value = shipPhone.value;
        billCompany.value = shipCompany.value;
        billAddress.value = shipAddress.value;
        billAddress2.value = shipAddress2.value;
        billCity.value = shipCity.value;
        billState.value = shipState.value;
        billZip.value = shipZip.value;
    } 
});

//Define Checkout Form Variables
const finalCheckoutStep = document.querySelector('.wpmc-step-payment');
    
//Observe Class Change in Final Checkout Step & Filter Delivery Options
var ob = new MutationObserver(function() {
    updateShippingMethods();
    updateCheckout();
});
ob.observe(finalCheckoutStep, {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ["class"]
});
    
//Run localPickUpSelection Function on Page Load
window.onload = function(){
 localPickUpSelection();
};

//Run delivery filter function after refreshing checkout
jQuery(document.body).on( 'updated_checkout', deliveryFilter);
    
//Run localPickUpSelection Function When Checkbox Value Changes
pickUpBtn.addEventListener('change', localPickUpSelection);
    
};
```